# H2DB : How to retrieve the date of the server?

Tags: java, date, h2

How to retrieve the date of the server using [H2 Database](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/h2/info)? I am developing an application in Java, but I'm blocked at this stage. How to retrieve the date of the server from Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the answer in the manual:

http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_timestamp

In Java

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select current_timestamp() from dual");
rs.next();
Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp(1);
rs.close();
stmt.close();
```

Comment: I already searched and I found CURRENT_DATE (), but the problem is that I do not know the table "dual" so I asked  a general manner, so you understand my question more clearly....

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi: OK, I wasn't sure, actually, what the question was. So the actual question is really about JDBC and how to handle such a query with H2...